# multiple functions in same button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am very beginner to HTML and javascript, so looking for some help.
I have a form and it has a submit button. When i click on the submit button the name of the button will change and it will do some action. when i click on the button again i have to do different actuion. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
        <form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return false">

        <input type="submit" id="reschedule" value="reschedule" onclick="changeContent()"/>
```

Javascript is :

```
        function changeContent(ref){
        alert(id)
        document.getElementById("reschedule").value="Submit"
        var editables = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText');
        for (var i = 1; i < editables.length; i++) {
            var newstate = !editables[i].isContentEditable;
            editables[i].contentEditable = newstate;
            editables[i].bgcolor='#FF0000'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("Submit").click) {
            alert("submit")
        }
    }
```

So when i click on reschedule the button name will change to submit. Now when i need to click on submit function i need to do some action. How can i do this.

Comment: when you use `submit` button the page will get refreshed and it wont meet your requirement. try replacing with `button`

Comment: Put an if condition in your function.

Comment: i think you can use click count and on the basis of that use if condition.

Answer (score 1):

you should `return false;` at the end of function so that your page will not refresh and you can do any thing on same page. use following javascript code

```
        function changeContent(ref){
        alert(id)
        document.getElementById("reschedule").value="Submit"
        var editables = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText');
        for (var i = 1; i < editables.length; i++) {
            var newstate = !editables[i].isContentEditable;
            editables[i].contentEditable = newstate;
            editables[i].bgcolor='#FF0000'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("Submit").click) {
            alert("submit")
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to my mind is checking the name of the button and do some action depending on that value. For example:

```
function changeContent(ref){
    if(document.getElementById("reschedule").value == "reschedule") {
        alert(id)
        document.getElementById("reschedule").value="Submit"
        var editables = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText');
        for (var i = 1; i < editables.length; i++) {
            var newstate = !editables[i].isContentEditable;
            editables[i].contentEditable = newstate;
            editables[i].bgcolor='#FF0000'
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("reschedule").value == "Submit") {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes i changed to button and it is working perfect.. Thanks for the help

Comment: I am using the button. but How i will submit the form if am using button. i have to change the document.form.action based on the button clicked. i know its little tricky but...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use buttons, once you submitted by clicking the submit button, then the page will be refreshed along with your action try to use **button**

**update your button**

```
 <input type="button" id="reschedule" value="reschedule" onclick="changeContent()"/>
```

then change your java script function like this

```
  function changeContent(ref){
        alert(id)
        document.getElementById("reschedule").value="Submit"
        var editables = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText');
        for (var i = 1; i < editables.length; i++) {
            var newstate = !editables[i].isContentEditable;
            editables[i].contentEditable = newstate;
            editables[i].bgcolor='#FF0000'
        }

        if (document.getElementById("Submit").click) {
            alert("submit");
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Update Setion :**

You can call your action using **Button** like this in javascript function:

```
 document.your_form_name.action = "your_action_name";
 document.your_form_name.submit();
```

Comment: I am using the button. but How i will submit the form if am using button.  i have to change the document.form.action based on the button clicked. i know its little tricky but...

Answer (score 0):

should be :

```
function changeContent()
{
    document.getElementById("reschedule").value = "Submit";
    var editables = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText');
    for (var i = 1; i < editables.length; i++) 
    {
        var newstate = !editables[i].isContentEditable;
        editables[i].contentEditable = newstate;
        editables[i].bgcolor='#FF0000'
    }
    if (document.getElementById("reschedule").value = "Submit") 
    {
       document.getElementById("reschedule").onclick=function(){
            alert('Hello this submit button click event');
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you wanted to make a comparison in the if statement, not an assignment.